# Lambda expression to search a Java Map using value

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have to implement the following method which takes in a value element in a Java Map and returns a Set of pojo encapsulating key & value objects in the Map.

```
public Set<CacheElement<K, V>> searchByValue(V v);
```

The CacheElement class is as follows:

```
public final class CacheElement<K, V> {

    private final K k;
    private final V v;

    public CacheElement(K k, V v) {
        super();
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public K getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public V getV() {
        return v;
    }   
}
```

I have written the following method to find the Set of key elements in the Map corresponding to the value passed.

```
public Set<CacheElement<K, V>> searchByValue(V v) {

    Set<K> keySet = this.cacheMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(v))
    .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return null;
}
```

I am not sure how to write lambda to pass the `keySet` to the Map and get back a Set containing matched `CacheElement<K,V>`.

I have written the following incomplete labmda:

```
    Set<CacheElement<K, V>> elements = this.cacheMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry ->keySet.contains(entry.getKey()))
    .map(entry -> new CacheElement<K, V>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

I need help in collecting the newly created CacheElement object in a set.

**The code is available at:
https://github.com/abnig/ancache**

Thanks

**Edit-1:**

**The cacheMap is**

```
private Map<K, V> cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>();
```

When I added the .collect operand

```
Set<CacheElement<K, V>> elements = cacheMap.entrySet().stream()
.filter(entry ->keySet.contains(entry.getKey()))
.map(entry -> new CacheElement<K, V>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())
.collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Then I get the following errors:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to Set<CacheElement<K,V>> line 92 Java Problem 

The method collect(Collectors.toSet()) is undefined for the type CacheElement<K,V>  line 95 Java Problem
```

Line #92 is: `Set<CacheElement<K, V>> elements = cacheMap.entrySet().stream()`

Line #95 is: `collect(Collectors.toSet()))`

**Edit-2**

[image]

Comment: are you not just looking for `.collect(Collectors.toSet());` or I'm I missing something?

Comment: @Aomine - getting errors on when I added collect. Please refer to edit -1 section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're primarily missing the `collect` (*toSet*) and `return`ing the result. You can also make sure to do the complete operation combining that logic with collect and return as:

```
public Set<CacheElement<K, V>> searchByValue(V v) {
    return this.cacheMap.entrySet().stream() // assuming Map<K, V> cacheMap
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(v)) // filter entries with same value 'v'
            .map(entry -> new CacheElement<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())) // map key and value to CacheElement
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // collect as a Set
}
```

Comment: getting errors on when I added collect. Please refer to edit -1 section

Comment: okay @AbNig, can you update the question with what type is your `cacheMap` of?

Comment: Added the comment and github url

Comment: @AbNig The code shared above compiles just fine with the details provided by you. Not sure if the question details are complete otherwise for an MCVE.

Comment: Added the screenshot for the error I am getting. Even maven build is giving same compilation error. The code is on github is same as on my local.

Comment: @AbNig just the wildest of the guess for that screenshot, are you missing the `this` is your second statement? As in `this.cacheMap`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185304/discussion-between-abnig-and-nullpointer).

Comment: @AbNig well in the screenshot you've shown, there are syntax errors, you're not closing the `map` intermediate method with a `)` parenthesis and you need to remove one more `)` after the collect. why don't you just copy the code provided here and past it (which I believe is syntactically correct)...